# .htaccess rewrite value of a query string parameter to URI folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know you mod_rewrite ninjas will answer this in a second. Google has index a bunch of URLs in the form `/p.php?p=Monkey` and I want to use .htaccess rewrite rule to provide a nice 301 permanent redirect to `/Monkey`

I have tried this code:

```
# Redirect old product page address to new location
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it does not work as required. The condition seems to match because the rule executes but it redirects to `/p=Monkey`. Almost there! What am I doing wrong? How do I backreference that all important value of `p` in the query string?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! My mistake was using a dollar sign for backreference when I should have used a percentage symbol. What a complete donkey I am! This likely happened because I mostly code in PHP where backreferences are prefixed with a dollar.

Furthermore I had to add a question mark to instruct it to completely remove the query string.

The functioning code is as follows:

```
# Redirect old product page address to new location
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$  
RewriteRule . /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 for good answer and also to counter undeserving downvote on question.